# setting VIew color in Android App

Tags: java, android

I've already spent a couple hours trying to figure it out:
I have colors defined in colors.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <color name="route_1">#C781D9</color>
    <color name="route_2">#015486</color>
....
</resources>
```

But when I try to set color of ImageView or Text those colors appear too dark and indistinguishable.

```
color_box.setColorFilter(my_color, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

However when I set color:

```
color_box.setColorFilter(Color.BLUE);
```

It works just fine. I have already tried:

```
int r = (my_color >> 16) & 0xFF;
int g = (my_color >> 8) & 0xFF;
int b = (my_color >> 0) & 0xFF;

color_box.setColorFilter(Color.rgb(r, g, b));
```

And it still gives me incorrect color.
Any ideas what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
color_box.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(my_color), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

This assumes that it will be called from inside an `Activity`. Also, it assumes that `my_color` is an int that equals `R.color.route_1` or `R.color.route_2`. You can just do the following also:

```
color_box.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.route_1), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```